# Couchbase - limit disk storage for a bucket

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to create bucket by limiting both RAM Size and Disk storage.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to limit disk storage.
By using **--bucket-ramsize** option in **couchbase-cli** I can create a bucket with specific amount of RAM.

Similarly is there a way to set disk storage limit of a bucket?

Comment: I cannot think of a valid scenario where disk storage limits would be necessary - and in fact, would be counter to the very idea of noSQL storage. Please describe your requirement in greater detail so we may suggest alternatives, if appropriate.

Comment: That being said, I believe you can set up disk space quota on the admin console.